# Perturbation/Homotopy of injective map by injective map is injective?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, homotopy-theory, perturbation-theory

The following is a thought that I am hoping is true.  I haven't been able to prove it and cannot seem to find a reference either.  Ideas and references are appreciated.

> Suppose $F_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$  are continuous injective maps and the determinant of the Jacobian of $F_i$ is positive on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider $L_t: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $ L_t= tF_0+(1-t)F_1$ for each $t \in [0,1]$.  Prove (or disprove) that there exists a $c>0$ such that $L_t$ is injective for each $t \in [0,c)$.